# How does selenium 2 (webdriver) implement WebElement

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, implementation

The scenario I'm considering is basic:

```
page = driver.open_page(URL)
linkElement = page.find_elements(XPATH)[0]
linkElement.click()
```

(I'm assuming I'm using a remote machine - i.e., remote driver). How does the server *know* on which element to click.

More generally, I couldn't find an overview of the selenium 2 implementation. That is, something that just *tells the story* but doesn't go line by line in the code, on the one hand, but something much more detailed than just the api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, there isn't a good one-size-fits-all "under-the-covers" look at how WebDriver implements the various parts of its API, largely because the actual implementation can be very different depending on the browser and the operating system. The closest you'll come is the various pages on the [project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/w/list).

To answer your specific question, the remote server creates a local instance of the client-side driver, and uses it to locate and click on the element. The driver (InternetExplorerDriver, FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver, etc.) commonly uses JavaScript to find the element and get its dimensions and location on the page. The element is scrolled into view, if needed, and an OS-level mouse event is sent to the browser window to simulate the click.

However, this is just the common case, and there are exceptions For instance, some browsers may find the element using means other than the JavaScript [automation atoms](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AutomationAtoms). Likewise, some drivers on some operating systems rely on synthetic events rather than OS-level, or so-called "native", events. The important thing to remember is that the remote server instantiates the same object you would if you invoked the driver locally, without using the Selenium remote server.

Comment: thanks! Can you please talk about how the client's webElements are synced with the server elements. E.g., say I do: `elem = page.get_elements(..)[0]` and `elem2 = elem.get_elements(..)`. How does the server "know" I have `elem2` (How does it know I'm pointing at that element?)? I'm guessing a request is performed to the server on each action I perform in the client side - is there a case where no request is performed?

Comment: Every command performed with the RemoteWebDriver makes a call to the remote server, using the [WebDriver JSON Wire Protocol](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol). Encoded in this protocol is the internal ID that WebDriver assigns to each element it finds. There is no caching done on the client side.

Comment: @JimEvans: can you tell me how the internal id is computed in the FirefoxWebdriver?

Comment: It's not "computed" in any way you can replicate for the FirefoxDriver; It's a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right:

You start remote web driver server. Through a remote driver client (that is your test), this server is told to fetch a page ('URL' is a variable set previously, for instance: `String URL = "http://www.asdf.com";`).

Then the server is told to find all the elements on the fetched page by some XPath ('XPATH' is something like `By.xpath("//div(@class = 'some_button_class')")` - this is java implementation of WebDriver and I'm not sure how it's used in Ruby). This command will return a list of WebElements - all the 'div' elements that look like this `<div class="some_button_class"><div>`. Check out [how XPath works](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp), if you're not familliar with it.

Since you're using `[0]` at the end of your command, you're telling server to return the first element from that list (the first div that looks like `<div class="some_button_class"><div>`)

At the end, you're telling the server to perform a click on that element. Server gets that command, translates it to javascript and injects that javascript to the page. Injected javascript triggers 'click' event on the page, and performs what would happen if a real user would click on the element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, this isn't what I meant. Say you do: `linkElem = page.find_elements(XPATH)` and then `childLink = linkElem.find_elements(XPATH_2)`. Finally, click on `childLink`. Now, how does the server know where to click?

Comment: Hmm.. well the same way as for the first web element. It gets an element of the DOM, and then another DOM element that is a child of the first one. Then it clicks on it (using javascript to perform the click). I'm not sure for the exact mechanism, but I guess some HTTP client is fetching a page, HTML parser is parsing it, and XPath parser is scanning the HTML page for DOM elements you asked for. Finally HTTP client is injecting Javascript and a click is performed...